# Python - Passing a TCP socket object to a multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, python-multiprocessing

I have a TCP server and client. At some point in the server script, I start a process, which needs to be able to get every new connection and send data to it. In order to do so, I have a `multiprocessing.Queue()`, to which I want to put every new connection from the main process, so that the process I opened can get the connections from it and send data to them. However, it seems that you cannot pass anything you want to a Queue. When I try to pass the connection (a socket object), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 266, in _feed
    send(obj)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Are there any alternatives that I could use?

Comment: You can't do that. `Queue` is intended to send Python objects, while sockets involve OS-specific data (such as socket fd), so they cannot be trivially passed to a subprocess.

Comment: Well, I found a workaround to the issue. However, I'd be really interested in seeing a way of actually doing this, even though you say it's impossible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sending a socket through a `multiprocessing.Queue` works fine starting with python3.4 because from that version a [`ForkingPickler` is used](https://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/5022ee7e13a2/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py#l241) to serialize the objects to be put in the queue, and that pickler knows how to serialize sockets and other objects containing a file handle.

The [`multiprocessing.reduction.ForkingPickler`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/reduction.py) class does already exist in python2.7 and can pickle sockets, it's just not used by `multiprocessing.Queue`.

If you can't switch to python3.4+ and really need similar functionality in python2.7 a workaround would be to create a function that uses the ForkingPickler to serialize objects, e.g:

```
from multiprocessing.reduction import ForkingPickler
import StringIO

def forking_dumps(obj):
    buf = StringIO.StringIO()
    ForkingPickler(buf).dump(obj)
    return buf.getvalue()
```

Instead of sending the socket directly you then need to send its pickled version and unpickle it in the consumer. Simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from socket import socket
import pickle

def handle(q):
    sock = pickle.loads(q.get())
    print 'rest:', sock.recv(2048)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock = socket()
    sock.connect(('httpbin.org', 80))
    sock.send(b'GET /get\r\n')
    # first bytes read in parent
    print 'first part:', sock.recv(50)

    q = Queue()
    proc = Process(target=handle, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    # use the function from above to serialize socket
    q.put(forking_dumps(sock))
    proc.join()
```

Making sockets pickleable only makes sense here in the context of multiprocessing, it would not make sense to write it to a file and use later or try to use it on a different pc or after the original process has ended. Therefore it wouldn't be a good idea to make sockets pickleable globally (e.g. by using the `copyreg` mechanisms).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! This way, I can pass sockets to the process and it works just fine! Thanks!